# Multiprocessing — receive all messages from multiple runtimes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-os

I've been trying to make a program that will allow multiple other programs to connect and send messages to a single port. The issue is that at some point, seemingly in the depths of the multiprocessing module, a call to `os.read` hangs on both ends.

Demo `receive.py`:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener


while True:
    with Listener(("localhost", 10000), authkey=b"test") as listener:
        with listener.accept() as connection:
            print(connection.recv())
```

Demo `send.py` (sends 1000 times to mimic multiple programs and expose the problem):

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client


for i in range(1000):
    successfully_sent = False
    while not successfully_sent:
        try:
            with Client(("localhost", 10000), authkey=b"test") as client:
                client.send(i)
        except (ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionResetError):
            continue
        successfully_sent = True
```

Any hints on how to force the processes to continue without losing any messages would be appreciated. I've considered using threading in receive.py to force timeouts, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way that addresses the underlying problem. Also, is this a bug?

Comment: how many messages are sent before it hangs? what OS?  What Python version?

Comment: Usually 60–600 messages on my system before it hangs. OS: Arch Linux, Python version: 3.9.0

Comment: I ran this code on Windows 10 Python 3.7 and did not encounter a problem. It does take quite a long time to execute - about 1 hour I think. sorry I don't have an idea for the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code! Did you run it without any changes? It takes well under a second to hang on my system, meaning that if it didn't hang it would complete all 1000 messages in less than a second.

Comment: As the hang happens (or at least has happened at least once) in the os module, I'll assume this is the result of a bug exposed by using Linux, and therefore submit a report.

Comment: I had modified the code with more try/except and more prints but now I've just rolled back to your code plus a  print("time: {}".format(time.time())) in the receive.py.  I set it to send 1000 and it did them at a pace of just a few per second.

Comment: I have tried your code on Linux (Raspberry pi ARM based).  The behavior is a lot different (versus Windows). The code executes very rapidly and stops at roughly 1500 messages.  My suggestion is to consider using websockets or else more basic low level socket commands.  I do not see a reason to use the multiprocessing module if you are going to be running two ore more separate process.  the multiprocessing module can be used to force Python to do a trick of spawning a second process.  I have written code that does this and it doesn't feel like this matches your intent.

Comment: I think you are right about that. I fixed my code by using more multiprocessing, but someday will probably rewrite it to use sockets.